# javascript for loop closure

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

i think i sort of understand the concept of hoisting when `var` is used to initialize `i` in a for loop and the concept of function closure. but why does the following code do not display an error as the final value of `i` is 4 and `arr[3]` is the highest index for `arr`?

why isn't the `i` in `arr[i]` linked to the `i` declared in the for-loop: `var i = 0` ?  **the point of this question is to understand the concept instead of getting the solution**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr[i])
}
```

compared to this, the output shows the final value of `i` (ie 3) three times. **i know that `let` should be used here**

```js
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
  funcs[i] = function() { 
    console.log("My value: " + i); 
  };
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();
}
```

Comment: In your first snippet, there is no function, there is no closure, and the `arr[i]` expression is evaluated *during* the loop, *before* `i` has reached its final value

Comment: but `arr[i]` still has the `i` variable inside, so why isn't it linked to the `i` declared in the for-loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "linked"? When evaluating the expression `arr[i]`, it evaluates the reference `i` to the current value of the variable `i`.

Comment: oh re-read ur first comment and i understand now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet the highest value is 4 but the max array index is 3 And since your loop is using array index length as it's max value, it doesn't go beyond the max index.

To understand the second example you'll need understand the difference between `var` and `let`.

The most basic explanation is `var` scopped to it's immediate function body (in your case outside of `for` loop, the same scope as `funcs` array)
while `let` scopped inside the enclosure (inside the `for` loop) and it basically creates create a new variable with each iteration of the loop, while `var` reuses the same variable.

Comment: This doesn't answer the main question "*Why does the [first snippet] do not display an error as the final value of i is 4 and arr[3] is the highest index for arr?*"

Comment: @Bergi, perhaps you are misunderstanding the difference between "value" and "index"... The condition of the loop set to limit `i` being less than the length of the array. The array length is 4 so the `i` cannot exceed 3 (less than 4)

Comment: `i` *does* exceed 3, it is set to the value `4` *after* the loop, as one can see in the second snippet in the question. OP is asking why the same doesn't happen in the first snippet.

Comment: Ok, now I see why this might be a little bit confusing. The way the `for` is structured you define start value , condition and than action for each iteration. Which gives you an impression that the sequence it will be executed in. In reality it does different: start value, action and then check the condition. So the loop increase `i` and than checks if it's within acceptable limit, if not, it stops the loop. So at the end you end up with i=4 and since in first example the output performed inside the loop it it only reaches to 3

Comment: However if you add another `console.log(i)` after the loop, it will show 4 as well.
And since `funcs` executed after the first loop, it's using the last value of `i` which at that point is 4. When `let` is used, variable `i` doesn't exist outside the loop, so when `funcs` executed they see it as block scopped variable at the moment it was created.

Comment: This is what you should add to your answer :-)